# Example of loading into RDS from S3 using SQL*Loader

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, sql-loader

Does anyone have a working sample of loading data into an Amazon AWS RDS Oracle database using SQL*Loader where the source file is on S3?

In principle it's clearly possible. The [Amazon RDS Data Import Guide for Oracle](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4173109646282306) documents using sqlldr. But the only sample there loads data from a local EC2 instance.

I have worked with RDS and with S3 and with SQL*Loader before, but I haven't worked with all 3 together. One sample would be really useful. (Related advice would be welcome too... but a sample is all I'm really looking for.)

Comment: Though Amazon documents _using_ sqlldr (a little bit), it doesn't document installing it at all. I found the process non-trivial, so I documented [installing SQL*Loader on Amazon Linux](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/sqlloader-ec2/‎).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought of two ideas how you could (at least theoretically) access the data if you are on Linux.

- mount S3 bucket using some kind of S3 FUSE. E.g. first hit on Google https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon
- create named pipe: `mkfifo oraclepipe` then configure SQL*Loader to read from the pipe probably using conventional path. And feed S3 file to the pipe: `wget -O oraclepipe http://s3.com/hash`.

We were using the second method on 9i to compress export online. And I do not recall problems with this approach. We ran two sessions from the shell script:

```
    gzip < oraclepipe > database.exp.gz &
    exp "username/passwd" FULL=y BUFFER=2048000 FILE=oraclepipe
```

Comment: For what it's worth... in the end we needed to process the files a bit. So I simply pulled the files from S3, tweaked them, then loaded them into RDS. The retrieval is fast enough that the potential gains of FuseOverAmazon or a pipe are really quite small for us.